# Additional target (or input) for custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I have a question with regard to using additional target for custom loss function.

Normally we have 2 inputs for the loss function, I would call it `y_predict` and `y_actual`. The MSE function would be:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred-y_true))
```

However, what if I have a third input, say `z` (for simplicity, assuming `z` has the same shape of `y_actual`)?

I found an answer in github, where they use a function inside another function, something like:

```
def custom_loss(z):
    def loss( y_pred, y_true):
        return K.mean(K.square(y_pred-y_true))*(y_pred – z)
    return loss
```

Then, we compile the model as:

```
model.compile(loss= custom_loss(z), optimizer='adam')
```

This is fine. However, I’m having an issue when “z” is dynamic when it comes to train data and valid data. That means, I have following data:

```
Train data: x_train, y_train, z_train
Valid data: x_valid, y_valid, z_valid
```

The loss function I desire would be:
Train loss:

```
loss = K.mean(K.square(y_pred-y_train)*(y_pred – z_train))
```

Valid loss:

```
loss = K.mean(K.square(y_pred-y_valid)*(y_pred – z_valid))
```

z_train and z_valid could be considered as an additional target/input of this loss function. 
Anyone has experience dealing with similar issues? Thanks.

Comment: I had my best go at editing this question; please review it in case I introduced an error. Your original was really ambiguous. To format code, copy/paste it in one go into the question, highlight the whole block, and either click on the `{}` button in the editor or use CTRL + K